# 10 million switching cycles with a hall effect sensor

Tags: arduino, switches

I am trying to build a pull switch for my invention that can survive 10 million cycles, and in a previous question here I recieved advice not to use a mechanical contact.

The other problem is size. The sensor assembly cannot be larger than 1x1x4 centimeters and the sliding distance can't be larger than 2 centimeters, otherwise I would need to do a mayor redesign of my invention.

There won't be more than 3-4 switching cycles per second, usually less, and the 10 million cycles is my extreme worst case scenario after several years of use. The sensor assembly will be sealed so there shouldn't be any problems with moisture, but perhaps some loose material from the casing due to wear and tear.

I've searched the net for a suitable pullswitch but found nothing that would work.

My questions are:

I tried using a hall effect switch with a permanent magnet and it worked fine, but wouldn't magnetism cause problems with EMC testing, CE and FCC rules?

I need to use a non latching hall effect switch, are there any reliability issues with those?

Do permanent magnets loose some of their strength over time? The sliding distance needed to close the switch cannot change more than a few milimeters.

Are there any other good alternatives besides hall effect sensors? Perhaps some form of piezo sensor? Preferably one that can work with the voltage levels of Arduino, though I have plenty of room on my PCB for resistors so wrong voltage shouldn't be a showstopper.

Answer (score 2):

> wouldn't magnetism cause problems with EMC testing, CE and FCC rules?

Not if it is a tiny permanent magnet - fridge magnets are typically not FCC certified. A varying magnetic field is more of a concern.

> hall effect switch, are there any reliability issues

Not if the Hall Effect switch is from a reputable manufacturer. Adding the identified switch(es) to the question will help provide additional insight.

> Do permanent magnets loose some of their strength over time?

Some types of permanent magnet lose field strength due to impacts, but a tiny rare earth magnet will probably outlast the rest of the device by orders of magnitude.

> Are there any other good alternatives besides hall effect sensors?

That would depend on the purpose and application of the switch, but capacitive sensing lends itself to really long operational life, with the actual switching by a MOSFET for instance.

There are many capacitive sensing products available, including some self-contained cap-sense pushbutton and proximity sensor (QTouch and QTouchADC) ICs from Atmel that do not even require a sensing  electrode, the IC itself works as the sensor. See these two references: [1](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc10752.pdf), [2](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc10760.pdf).

Another option is light path interruption sensing, such as using an LED and a photodiode, or prepackaged such sensors with both parts integrated.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is a microswitch. These are not particularly small, despite the name; they are sealed industrial grade switches designed to be operated by machinery (e.g. to limit motion)

Some microswitches [like this](http://uk.farnell.com/itw-switches/19n502l63/microswitch-v4-long-lever/dp/521905) [or this](http://uk.farnell.com/omron-electronic-components/d3v-163-1a4/microswitch-spdt-16a-long-lever/dp/2068240) are rated for 10 million mechanical operations. In the case of this one, it is only rated for 100,000 electrical operations at full load, but switching small currents its life should be dominated by the mechanical rating.

They are arranged to be operated in a variety of ways : this one has a lever which could be moved by a pull cord. If so, you should arrange the connection such that if pulled too hard, something else takes the excess pull, not the switch!

Answer (score 0):

For the root question of EMC, CE, FCC and magnets...

The only issue likely is extream magnetism hazards. The sort that leads to physical trapping of fingers, skin etc when handling . This is not the sort of magnet you would normally use with a hall sensor as they don't need that sort of strength.

The other issue is Induced currents in conductive parts. The magnet has to be moving for this to be an issue and at 4 cycles a second your talking theoretical issue unless you have extream magnatism or hundreds (thousands?) of turns of a coil nearby.

So generally there is no issue.

As for finding a pullswitch, I think it is unlikely you will find one.. this is where you have to modify a switch or make your own...

Answer (score 0):

Howe about optical? LED and photo-diode with the light blocked by a slider. When you pull on the slider, it moves out of the way.